# Trying to get propertyof non-object yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am starting to learn Yii framework so I am a beginner. I am struggling.  I want to fetch the data from database using yii2 framework. This is my controller

```
 public  function actionView()
{


    $this->view->title = 'List Hotels';
    $items = ArrayHelper::map(Hotel::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');

        return $this->render('index', [
            'items' => $items,


        ]);

}
```

In my view file, I used the fetched data as below;

```
   <?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use yii\helpers\Html;

 $this->title = 'Hotel list';
 $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
 ?>

<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>

<p> <?= $item-> name ?></p>
<p> <?= $item->address ?></p>
<p> <?= $item->description ?></p>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I wrote var_dumps($items) under $items I can see the  datas. However in the view  It says Trying to get property 'name' of non-object. What did I wrong here please guide me. THanks for your time.

Comment: You pass `$items` (with `-s`), but use `$item` (without `-s`) and I do not see any loop of `$items`, so yes, `$item === null`

Comment: I am sorry, I miswrote my code. I edited it. Can u please check now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayHelper::map()
```

Returns an array where, in your case, second argument passed is a key, the third is a value. So you need to access its elements as an array elements instead of class properties. Like:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $key => $value): ?>

    <p> <?= $key ?></p>
    <p> <?= $value ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

More details here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#map()-detail

But if you need to access data as class properties change the line in your controller:

```
$items = ArrayHelper::map(Hotel::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
```

to:

```
$items = Hotel::find()->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $items = Hotel::find()->all();
```

I should not add Array Helper